# How should I insert try-except in this scenario

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, valueerror, try-except

> **Task1**
>
> Write a script that reads a string from STDIN and raise ValueError
>   exception if the string has more than 10 characters or else prints the
>   read string.

I wrote the code like this

```
a = input("Enter a string")
if(len(a) > 10):
    raise ValueError
else:
    print(a)
```

> **Task2**
>
> Use `try ... except` clauses. Print the error message inside except
>   block.

I am now confused about how to use `try-except` here because to print any message in `except` block the program has to fail at `try` block.

My input will be `PythonIsAmazing`

Comment: Why would you want to print an error message if the program didn't fail?

Comment: this is a task assigned to me for practice on error handling

Comment: Your program **will** fail because you are raising an exception...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just wrap the whole thing in `try ... except` as follows:

```
a = input("Enter a string: ")

try:
    if(len(a) > 10):
        raise ValueError
    print(a)
except ValueError:
    print("String was longer than 10 characters")
```

Alternatively, if you had lots of different `ValueErrors` that might be raised, you could give each a separate error message:

```
a = input("Enter a string: ")

try:
    if(len(a) > 10):
        raise ValueError("String was longer than 10 characters")
    print(a)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

**Eg:**

```
Enter a string: test
test

Enter a string: PythonIsAmazing
String was longer than 10 characters
```